# laravelcollective select option in laravel

Tags: laravel

How to show value select option when install `laravelcollective /html` in laravel?

blade

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="target">Categoory</label>
        {!! Form::select('categories', $categories, null, [
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id' => 'target',
        ]) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
public function index() 
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('user::admin.users.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

demo

[image: select]

Comment: and what value do you want to show for the select option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print your categories like this:

```blade
{!! Form::select('categories', $categories->pluck('name', 'id'), null, [
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id' => 'target',
        ]) !!}
```